# insert string with linebreaks into database php - cakephp

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a string which will contain an address and which is to be stored in a single database field. The address needs to have line breaks after each line in the address but I'm having trouble creating a string which has the appropriate format.

I'm trying like this:

```
$address = $userName.'\n'.
           $addOne.'\n'.
            ($addTwo != '' ? $addTwo.'\n' : '').
            $city.'\n'.
            $postcode.'\n'.
            $country.'\n';
```

but that creates the string with the \n in it.

How can I make a string which has line breaks in it that get saved in the DB as such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `"` instead of `'` like this

```
$address = $userName."\n".
   $addOne."\n".
    ($addTwo != "" ? $addTwo."\n" : "").
    $city."\n".
    $postcode."\n".
    $country."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something like this (to me personally it looks more readable, but performs the same function):

```
$address = $userName."\n"
$address .= $addOne."\n"
$address .= ($addTwo != "" ? $addTwo."\n" : "")
$address .= $city."\n"
$address .= $postcode."\n"
$address .= $country."\n";
```